# Using numeric trunc on a string column

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use `trunc()` on a BigQuery "numeric" string column to truncate it from 3 decimals to 2 decimals.

This works when the string is specified inside trunc:

```sql
select
  "yey" as x,
  trunc(numeric '50.239', 2) as trunced

    x trunced
1 yey   50.23
```

But if I want to run this on a table it doesn't work:

```sql
with t as(
  select
     "yey" as x,
     '50.239' as y
)

select x, trunc(numeric y, 2) as y_trunc from t
```

And produces the error `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "y" at [7:25]`

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**numeric '50.239'** is *a numeric literal representation*, not type casting. You should use **cast(y as numeric)** if you want to convert a string column to a numeric column.

```sql
with t as(
  select
     "yey" as x,
     '50.239' as y
)

select x, trunc(cast(y as numeric), 2) as y_trunc from t
```

[image]

###### references

- [NUMERIC literals](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#numeric_literals)

> You can construct NUMERIC literals using the NUMERIC keyword followed by a floating point value in quotes.

```sql
Examples:

SELECT NUMERIC '0';
SELECT NUMERIC '123456';
SELECT NUMERIC '-3.14';
```